# How to correctly sum an integer inside .map function in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm new to Scala and Spark, trying to create a pair-like RDD in Spark, assigning an Int as key for each line and summing +1.

```
val mapUrls = urls.map{
var cont = 0
x => 
cont += 1
(cont,x)
}
```

the problem is that somehow, the cont variable goes back to 1 after certain time.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this is what you want?

```
urls.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap)
```

Your code just cannot work correctly. Remember that Spark is distributed framework and there is no shared memory. Each task has updates its own `cont`.

Comment: Thanks man, that's exactly what i wanted.
I found that there is a lot of functions for the needs day to day.
But just for studying purposes, there is another way to solve this??

Comment: Not by modifying variable in a closure. You check `zipWithIndex` sourc to understand how this can be implemented.